# Finding the month and year with Max sales in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns -
ID, Year, Month, Sales

The data is in long format. So, for 10 unique IDs and 5 years of data I will have 10(IDs) * 5(Years) * 12(Months) = 600 rows

I want to extract the following information -

1. Find out the Year and Month in which the sales was maximum for each ID
2. Find out the Year in which there was maximum sales for each ID

What should be the query in SQL. I use MySQL 5.6

Comment: *I use MySQL.* What is precise version of your MySQL?

Comment: @Akina I have a pretty old one. 5.6

Comment: Imagine that 2 separate Year-Month pair (or 2 separate Year value) shows the same Sales value which is maximal one. What output do you need in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mysql 5.6 window function will not work. So you can use subquery in `where clause` to get your desired result:

```
 create table yourtable (ID int, Year int, Month int, Sales int);
 insert into yourtable values(1,2020,1,119);
 insert into yourtable values(2,2020,1,105);
 insert into yourtable values(1,2020,2,110);
 insert into yourtable values(1,2021,1,120);
```

Query#1

```
   select id, year, month, sales from yourtable a
     where sales= (select max(sales) from yourtable b where a.id=b.id)
```

Output:

| id | year | month | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020 | 1 | 105 |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 120 |

Query#2:

```
 select id,year,sum(sales)from yourtable a
 group by id,year
 having sum(sales)=(
                     select sum(sales) from yourtable b where a.id=b.id
                     group by id,year 
                     order by sum(sales) 
                     desc limit 1
                    )
```

Output:

| id | year | sum(sales) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 229 |
| 2 | 2020 | 105 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e098d258b6edd70870d8c2329fc6afff)*

Comment: As I understand query #2 must return the year where summarized monthly sales shows maximal sum.

Comment: @Akina you are right. Thanks a lot. Revising my answer.